# Python SUDS SOAP request to https service 401

Tags: python, https, suds

I am trying use SUDS and am stuck trying to figure out why I can't get authentication to work (or https).

The service I am trying to access is over https with basic digest authentication.  Based on the debugs it seems to be using http instead of https.  But not really sure what I am missing.  Any clue is appreciated.

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.xsd.schema').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.wsdl').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def main():
    url = 'https://blah.com/soap/sp/Services?wsdl'
    credentials = dict(username='xxxx', password='xxxx')
    t = HttpAuthenticated(**credentials)
    client = Client(url, location='https://blah.com/soap/sp/Services', transport=t)
    print client.last_sent()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Debug Output:

> DEBUG:suds.wsdl:reading wsdl at: https://blah.com/soap/sp/Services?wsdl ...
>   DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (https://blah.com/soap/sp/Services?wsdl)
>   
> snip ...
>    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds-0.4-py2.7\suds\reader.py", line 95, in download
>     fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
>
> File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds-0.4-py2.7\suds\transport\http.py", line 173, in open
>       return HttpTransport.open(self, request)
>
> File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds-0.4-py2.7\suds\transport\http.py", line 64, in open
> raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)
>
> suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required

Comment: First for correctness...It should be just be 'digest authentication' not 'basic digest authentication.'  The types of auth are: 'digest' and 'basic.'  So I was confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Suds provides two `HttpAuthenticated` classes, one in the `suds.transport.http` module and the second in the `suds.transport.https` module. It appears your instantiating from `suds.transport.http`, however since your URL is `https://`, you may want to try `suds.transport.https.HttpAuthenticated`.

Comment: +1. `suds.transport.https.HttpAuthenticated` wasn't in suds' doc. Your solution was the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this problem and found a solution that works for me.
My server was using NTLM authentication, so for `suds` to work with it, I just had to follow the "Windows (NTLM)" section in the [documentation](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation).

First install [python-ntlm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ntlm), and then you can write:

```
from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated
ntlm = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username='xx', password='xx')
client = Client(url, transport=ntlm)
```