# Django strange behavior with suds

Tags: django, web-services, authentication, suds

I'm using suds to consume a WebService and i'm facing a strange error.

When I first make a call to the WebService, it fails. When I refresh the page once it fails too. When I refresh the page a second time, it works.

Do you guys have any idea why it only works when I refresh the page twice?

urls.py :

```
url(r'^test/$', views.formulaire),
url(r'^test/(?P<rechercher>.*\d+)/$', views.formulaire), #optional = .*
```

views.py :

```
url = 'https://myWebService.com/Action.asmx?WSDL'
username='username'
password='password'

client = Client(url=url, username=username, password=password)
```

The first two time I get the following message :

```
TransportError at /blog/test/
HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\transport\http.py" in open
  67.             return self.u2open(u2request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\transport\http.py" in u2open
  132.         return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in open
  470.             response = meth(req, response)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in http_response
  580.                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in error
  502.         result = self._call_chain(*args)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in _call_chain
  442.             result = func(*args)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in http_error_401
  901.                                           url, req, headers)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in http_error_auth_reqed
  879.                         return self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in retry_http_basic_auth
  889.             return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in open
  470.             response = meth(req, response)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in http_response
  580.                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in error
  508.             return self._call_chain(*args)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in _call_chain
  442.             result = func(*args)

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py" in http_error_default
  588.         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

During handling of the above exception (HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.1-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\wamp\www\crepes_bretonnes\blog\views.py" in formulaire
  91.                 client = Client(url=url, username=username, password=password)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\client.py" in __init__
  115.         self.wsdl = reader.open(url)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\reader.py" in open
  150.             d = self.fn(url, self.options)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\wsdl.py" in __init__
  136.         d = reader.open(url)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\reader.py" in open
  74.             d = self.download(url)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\reader.py" in download
  92.             fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\transport\https.py" in open
  62.         return HttpTransport.open(self, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.4.egg\suds\transport\http.py" in open
  69.             raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)

Exception Type: TransportError at /blog/test/
Exception Value: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into the same issue before in production due to not using the right `transport` class. In my case, for production https is forced while development is strictly http.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697210/python-suds-soap-request-to-https-service-401) -

*Suds provides two HttpAuthenticated classes, one in the suds.transport.http module and the second in the suds.transport.https module. It appears your instantiating from suds.transport.http, however since your URL is https://, you may want to try suds.transport.https.HttpAuthenticated.*