# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object When Trying to Use Windows Authentication ( Python NTLM) with Suds

Tags: python, windows, authentication, suds

I am trying to connect to a SOAP API and authenticate using Windows Authentication. I am using suds-py3 and have installed python-ntlm3. [I tried following what was outlined in this Stack Exchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697210/python-suds-soap-request-to-https-service-401)
but am getting the following error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. I am relatively new to this and not sure how to diagnose this problem...my code and the full traceback are below. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d1f3f5890266> in <module>
      2 ntlm = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username='user', password='pass')
      3 url = 'https://xxxxxremovedforpostxxx/winauthwebservices/sswinauthwebservice.asmx'
----> 4 client = Client(url, transport=ntlm)

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py in __init__(self, url, **kwargs)
    108         self.set_options(**kwargs)
    109         reader = DefinitionsReader(options, Definitions)
--> 110         self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
    111         plugins = PluginContainer(options.plugins)
    112         plugins.init.initialized(wsdl=self.wsdl)

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py in open(self, url)
    149         d = cache.get(id)
    150         if d is None:
--> 151             d = self.fn(url, self.options)
    152             cache.put(id, d)
    153         else:

    c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\suds\wsdl.py in `__init__(self, url, options)`
        133         log.debug('reading wsdl at: %s ...', url)
        134         reader = DocumentReader(options)
    --> 135         d = reader.open(url)
        136         root = d.root()
        137         WObject.__init__(self, root)

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py in open(self, url)
     76         d = cache.get(id)
     77         if d is None:
---> 78             d = self.download(url)
     79             cache.put(id, d)
     80         self.plugins.document.parsed(url=url, document=d.root())

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py in download(self, url)
     92         fp = store.open(url)
     93         if fp is None:
---> 94             fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
     95         content = fp.read()
     96         fp.close()

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\https.py in open(self, request)
     59     def open(self, request):
     60         self.addcredentials(request)
---> 61         return HttpTransport.open(self, request)
     62 
     63     def send(self, request):

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py in open(self, request)
     61             u2request = u2.Request(url, None, headers)
     62             self.proxy = self.options.proxy
---> 63             return self.u2open(u2request)
     64         except HTTPError as e:
     65             raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py in u2open(self, u2request)
    117             return url.open(u2request)
    118         else:
--> 119             return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
    120 
    121     def u2opener(self):

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 532             response = meth(req, response)
    533 
    534         return response

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    641             response = self.parent.error(
--> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    643 
    644         return response

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    562             http_err = 0
    563         args = (dict, proto, meth_name) + args
--> 564         result = self._call_chain(*args)
    565         if result:
    566             return result

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\ntlm3\HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py in http_error_401(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
    133 
    134     def http_error_401(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
--> 135         return self.http_error_authentication_required('www-authenticate', req, fp, headers)
    136 
    137 

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\ntlm3\HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py in http_error_authentication_required(self, auth_header_field, req, fp, headers)
     38             if auth_header_value is not None and 'ntlm' in auth_header_value.lower():
     39                 fp.close()
---> 40                 return self.retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(req, auth_header_field, None, headers)
     41 
     42     def retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(self, req, auth_header_field, realm, headers):

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\ntlm3\HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py in retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(self, req, auth_header_field, realm, headers)
    100             # some Exchange servers send two WWW-Authenticate headers, one with the NTLM challenge
    101             # and another with the 'Negotiate' keyword - make sure we operate on the right one
--> 102             m = re.match('(NTLM [A-Za-z0-9+\-/=]+)', auth_header_value)
    103             if m:
    104                 auth_header_value, = m.groups()

c:\program files\alteryx\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\re.py in match(pattern, string, flags)
    170     """Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    171     a match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 172     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
    173 
    174 def fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```